# Sum of any two numbers in array equal number from another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, rake-task

I have two arrays, `array1` and `array2`. I want to check if there are any 2 distinct numbers in `array1` so that their sum is a another distinct number in `array2`. Here is what I have tried, but it does not seem to be working exactly as i want it to.

```
array1.each do |k|
  array1.each do |l|
    array2.each do |m|
      if k + l == m
        # do something with k, l, m
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What happens? Seems legit.

Comment: `a1.product(a2).any? { |combination| a3.include?(combination.inject(:+)) }` ?

Comment: I just updated my question. I have two arrays instead of three, I believe that there is a problem with nesting an iteration of the same array inside one loop maybe.. this is a smaller part of my code and i cant figure out exactly what the issue is

Comment: Now you have the issue that you might pick the same number twice. Aka if you have `[1]` and `[2]`, you will still find `2 == 1 + 1`. Other than that, it seems legit.

Comment: Ah.. yes. how do you think i could stop that from happening?

Comment: I just re-read your question. You said you wanted the numbers to be distinct. Does that mean that no matches should be found for `array1 = [1, 1]; array2 = [2]` and `array1 = [0, 1]; array2 = [1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might pick the same number twice. Aka with

```
array1 = [1]
array2 = [2]
```

You will get `2 == 1 + 1`. To avoid this, you could use [`Array#combination`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-combination):

```
array1.combination(2).select { |x, y| array2.include? x + y }.each do |x, y|
  # do something with x, y and x + y
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this really is very ruby'ish and i am no rubyist, i need a reference to that particular number in the second array too. say z

Comment: @Mordred, well, `z = x + y` so I don't see the problem there. As for the answer being ruby'ish, I can expand if you want me to.

Comment: oh yeah, of course. My brain was fixed on getting a reference. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As we merely want to know if `m+n` is an element of the second array, where `m` and `n` are *distinct* elements of the first array (which I assume to mean `m != n`), we will want to use [Emumerable#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F).

```
require 'set'

def any_pair?(arr1, arr2)
  set = arr2.to_set
  arr1.uniq.combination(2).any? { |n,m| set.include?(n+m) }
end

any_pair? [3,1,6,1,4], [1,2,6,7]
  #=> true
any_pair? [3,1,6,1,4], [1,2,6]
  #=> false
```

We need to check if the sum of two values in `arr1` is a member of `arr2` up to `n*(n-1)` times, where `n` is `arr1.size`. We could use [Array#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F), but this operation can be made much more efficient by converting `arr2` to a set as an initial step. Set membership lookups (which are implemented as a hash lookup) are very fast.

If we wish to instead return all distinct pairs of elements of `arr1` whose sum is a member of `arr2`, the method would be changed to the following.

```
def all_pairs(arr1, arr2)
  set = arr2.to_set
  arr1.uniq.combination(2).select { |n,m| set.include?(n+m) }
end

all_pairs [3,1,6,1,4], [1,2,6,7]
  #=> [[3, 4], [1, 6]] 
all_pairs [3,1,6,1,4], [1,2,6]
  #=> []
```